# length of continous bits 1 stream followed by 0

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

Was interview question, so looking for what could be non-obvious solutions.

Say there is big stream of 1111...111100000...000

find length (number) of 1.

You may assume here 1 is a Set Bit.

How it will change if 1 is symbol, say like aaa..aaaabbbb...bbbbb

One solution I could propose was look 1st bit/symbol, then keep doubling the interval, like then look 3rd, then 7th and so on. when ever you hit 0 or other symbol, then move back towards last position, again using divide and conquer.

Comment: Do you know the total length of the stream and have random access to it? Are the 1s and 0s parts guaranteed to be non-empty?

Comment: You said this was an interview question...were they approaching it from a theoretical direction (big 0 algorithm size and such) or an implementation one (efficient use of real-world mechanisms like caching and processor architecture)?

Comment: The doubling of the interval will not work, unless you know that after a `0` you will never have any more `1`s. In that case you need to check each symbol individually (or in small, but equal groups, like 32 or 64 bits)

Comment: we know there is no 1 once 0 is seen

Answer (score 4):

If you have random access to the stream and the stream's length is known, you can do it with a variant of binary-search in O(log n).

Alternatively, you can & with 0x1 and, if zero, increment counter and right shift by 1. Or, you can check whether whole bytes (words, double words, quad words, etc) are non-zero to more quickly find the block where the ones start. Either way, that's O(n).

Comment: It's pretty rare to have random access to a _stream_.

Comment: Assume big bit/symbol array is given.

Answer (score 3):

If you are to traverse the bit stream linearly you could process it in 32-bit chunks, performing a bitwise AND with 0xFFFFFFFF (all 1s) and updating your count accordingly.

This exploits the fact that modern CPUs can typically perform bitwise operations on 32-bit words as a single atomic action.

If the result of the AND is 0xFFFFFFFF then you know there are potentially more bits to follow and hence must inspect the next 32-bit word.  Otherwise you simply increment your counter and cease looping.

Comment: Once you find the first 32bit chunk (`x`) that _isn't_ `0xFFFFFFFF`, then (`~x+1`) will result in only the last 1 being set.  That might or might not help count the number of remaining 1s

Comment: For the first 32-bit chunk that isn't all 1s the AND op could still yield a result with a number of 1s set (e.g. 0xFFFFFFFE), not just the last 1.  You could then explicitly count the number of 1s or use a look-up table to determine the count of this final chunk.

Comment: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogDeBruijn
`count += MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition2[((~x+1) * 0x077CB531U) >> 27];`  It's only 6 ops to calculate the bits in the last one, with no branch.

Comment: Why on earth would you write 'x & 0xFF == 0xFF' if you can write simply 'x == 0xFF?' You need comparison in both cases.

Comment: @Mooing: Question said it big stream or array, length is known. So unsure to assume it as integer of any theoritical word size like 32/64/xxx bits.

Comment: The binary search answer changes the scale of the problem from O(n) to O(log n ). This is an inner loop optimization, but you are still checking every bit. As N gets large the binary search answer above will outperform any linear traversal by many orders of magnitude

Answer (score 0):

binary search to find the index s.t. the ith bit is set and the (i+1)th isn't.
add a special case for the first bit being unset and the last bit being set, and you're done